# asp.net updatepanel and validators problem

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

i have read [ASP.NET Validators inside an UpdatePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814/asp-net-validators-inside-an-updatepanel)
but i still have this error:
**'Page_Validators' is not defined**

here is what i have installed on the server (were the errors occur):

.net framework 2.0 service pack 2

.net framework 3.0 service pack 2

.net framework 3.5 service pack 1

ajax extensions 1.0

i have an 2.0 solution with ajax 1 which i opened in visual studio 2008 and therefore it automatically converted it to 3.5

on my laptop i don't have the error and i run vista with the .net framework 3.5 and also sp1
so i don't see any differences.

the ajax dll in the bin dir is 1.0.20229.0 i hope that helps :)

what do i need to install and/or update on the server to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to set enableclientscript to false of the validators that are in the updatepanel

but it is still wierd that the error only occurs on the production environment