# jQuery dialog stops showing after ajax postback with asp:updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, datepicker, updatepanel

I have `asp validator` controls and `jquery dialog`.
I'm using `asp:UpdatePanel` for `ajax`.

After page is refreshed, `validators` still are validating fields by showing `*` symbol if something is wrong, however, my `jQuery` pop up does not pop up anymore.

It stopped working after I fixed the problem when `datepicker` stopped showing after `postback`. To fix that I added the following code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().beginAsyncPostBack();
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        $('.datepicker1, .datepicker2').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
            defaultDate: "1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonth: 1
        });
    }
});
```

That fixed `datepicker` problem. However, it broke, validators logic that displayed validation pop up. Here is the code for validation:

```
function ValidateFields() {
    var isValid = false;

    isValid = Page_ClientValidate('vgForm');

    if(!isValid){
        $('#errorDisplay').dialog({
           title: "Validation Error",
           modal: true,
           resizable: false,
           width: 250,
           buttons:{
           Close: function(){
                $(this).dialog('close');
                }
           }
       });
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

What is the right way to fix that?

---

I found some fix to the problem, but now, as soon as page loads, Validators show `*` and jQuery pop up is displayed, if required fields fail validation.

Here is an update:

```
<script language="javascript">

    function ValidateFields() {
        var isValid = false;

        isValid = Page_ClientValidate('vgForm');

            if (!isValid) {
                $('#errorDisplay').dialog({
                    title: "Validation Error",
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    width: 250,
                    buttons: {
                        Close: function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function DatePickerInit() {
            $(".datepicker1, .datepicker2").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
                defaultDate: "1w",
                changeMonth: true,
                numberOfMonth: 1
            });

        }

</script>

<script language="javascript">

    $(function () {

        ValidateFields();
        DatePickerInit();
    });
</script>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="SM" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(ValidateFields);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(DatePickerInit);
</script>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

//Form and GridView goes here

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<div id="errorDisplay">
     <asp:ValidationSummary ID="vSum" runat="server" ShowSummary="true" ValidationGroup="vgForm"></asp:ValidationSummary>   
</div>
```

Comment: Your issue is that an UpdatePanel replaces all its contents on an update. It means that all the events subscribed to your fields are no longer subscribed, because your fields have been replaced by new ones. In the same way that you had to bind the jQuery datepicker plugin after a postback, you have to bind the validation method to whatever it was bound to in your `EndRequestHandler`

Comment: Can you give me an idea on how to bind it in `EndRequestHandler`. I'm not sure how to accomplish that. Thank's a lot

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Can you tell me if your validators are inside of the UpdateTemplate? Where do you initially bind your `ValidateFields()` function?

Comment: `Validators` are inside `UpdatePanel` and `ValidatorSummary` is outside. I'm invoking `ValidateFields` function when clicking on a `asp:button` control which is inside of `UpdatePanel` as well. I can update my post to reflect, approximately what I have in my page.

Comment: What happens is, initially when my page loads, validators are firing and show `*` symbol on required fields. I do not need that. I want them to fire only when I click the `button`.

Comment: First things first, let's start with the original issue. Do you really need the `button` to be inside the UpdatePanel? If you really do, you need to bind the `ValidateFields` function in your `EndRequestHandler`, because the button will be replaced with a new one during `postback`. You could easily use `jQuery`'s event `click`, since I see you are using jQuery UI. For the validators inside of the UpdatePanel, it's going to be a bit more complicated. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814/asp-net-validators-inside-an-updatepanel) to give yourself a clue on what you need to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115863/discussion-between-bishopbarber-and-gene).